# Create DocumentFile from Uri

Tags: android, storage-access-framework, documentfile

Using SAF I create a file in the file provider.
In onActivityResult I then persist the permissions to that file and store the Uri into the shared preferences.
Later I write data into the file.

This seems to work. except if the file was deleted/moved/renamed or basically if it no longer exists.

I can check whether it exists or not using:

```kotlin
val file = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(applicationContext, uri)
if (!file!!.exists())
```

But this doesn't solve the problem that I can not write my data using `contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri)`, for I get a `FileNotFoundException`.

Is there a way to create the file using the stored Uri, while I should still have the permissions persisted?

Comment: "while I should still have the permissions persisted?" -- I'm not certain that is true, if the content no longer exists. You may need to go through `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` again (as I assume that is what you used to get the `Uri` originally).

Comment: @CommonsWare, I did use `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` and I persisted the permissions using `contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(uri, readWriteFlags)`. I haven't explicitly released them is what I meant, and using SAF to create a new document is exactly what I want to avoid, as I write data in a background service

Comment: "I haven't explicitly released them is what I meant" -- you are assuming that they still exist, despite the document no longer existing. "as I write data in a background service" -- raise a `Notification` to let your user know that you cannot write anymore due to their changes, and use that to steer the user to create a new document for you to use.

Comment: @CommonsWare, that's my last resort, but for now the question is, if there's ANY was to avoid that?

Comment: You might want to update your question with the code that is trying to write the content and the complete stack trace.

Comment: `openOutputStream` throws `FileNotFoundException` when the file no longer exists. That's all